# when/who proposed and developed L(R) as a model of ZF?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

In trying to understand L($\bf{R}$) better, I've not found an exposition of its origin as a model of ZF.  It was around before the end of the 1960s, and one might imagine there was an impetus for something "bigger" than Goedel's constructible universe L after Cohen's results on the CH; then again, Mycielski and Steinhaus proposed the axiom of determinacy (AD) in 1962, and that certainly has many desirable consequences in L($\bf{R}$), but hey, who knew (or intuited) such things early on?

So my **question** really asks for an overview of the chronology of what was conjectured/proved when, regarding key properties of the model.  (To clarify what I mean by key properties, I am thinking of things like "Dependent Choice holds" or "there's no nonmeasurable sets" or (under appropriate large cardinals) "AD holds", and so on.)

Comment: I do not understand the question. Models of the form $L(X)$ were considered since at least the mid-50s, through work of Hajnal. Whether $X$ is $\mathbb R$ or not is irrelevant to "its origin as a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$". Is this what you are asking, or are you interested in $L(\mathbb R)$ specifically?  Your second paragraph seems to ask something entirely different, this time explicitly about $L(\mathbb R)$. The two paragraphs appear to be separate questions.

Comment: I am interested in L(R) specifically, yes.  The fact that L(X) type models were considered in the 1950s dispenses with my (admittedly speculative) musings in the my first paragraph.  They were not mere idle speculations, however, they were an attempt to give potential answerers some insight into what was driving my curiosity about L(R).  I am still wondering about who/what/when; in particular, e.g. I know in Solovay's 1970 article showing a model of "all sets, Lebesgue measurable" he conjectured that there would yet be found some large cardinal that implied Lebesgue measurability (continued)

Comment: in a model of ZF with Dependent Choice.  (Sorry, I don't have that article right in front of me, I am going by recent memory.)  Perhaps I may borrow some phraseology of Penelope Maddy in an attempt to clarify my interest in L(R): speaking of L, she says (in her Believing the Axioms) that before Scott, people doubted that V=L; afterwards they knew why.  Perhaps there is some comparable Aha! moment when people realized that L(R) was really the kind of model that was really as desirable as they'd suspected (for doing Lebesgue measure, having Determinacy hold, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Diving into what literature I could access, I have come up with an answer, in  "story" form, which more or less satisfies my inquiry.  (Perhaps it is an answer to a slightly different, or more well posed question.)  In any case, it makes sense (so far) to me...

As the 1960s dawned there must have been a certain air of anticipation in the mathematical world.
Godel's universe L of constructible sets had stood as a major advance for over two decades, an important inner model of the ZF
axioms.  It enjoyed the principle of Choice.  It showed the CH could not be disproved from the axioms of ZFC alone.
Yet there was a sense of things impending; many, even Godel, believed the CH was not "really" true (and might well be
a genuinely mathematical statement which was independent of ZFC.)  Dana Scott had shown that existence of a measurable cardinal
was incompatible with the axiom V=L. Impetus was thus given to the search for some bigger, better inner model(s).

New results and proposals now began to arise, such as Paul Cohen's invention of the powerful method of forcing.
Around the same time, Jan Mycielski and Hugo Steinhaus proposed their Axiom of Determinacy.  AD was quickly seen to contradict Choice,
but Cohen had shown both the CH and the AC to be independent of the ZF axioms; perhaps an accommodation might be found, short of the
full principle of Choice, for this intriguing new concept of Determinacy.

Ulam's old investigations of the measure problem had led to speculation about large cardinals (i.e. (2-valued) measurable) and
about any measure at all existing on the power set of the reals (real-valued measurable).  It was not long before Robert Solovay
showed the equiconsistency of existence of a measurable cardinal with a measure (indeed an extension of Lebesgue measure) on the power
set of $\bf{R}$.

Of course, a way to look for a model in which all sets were Lebesgue measurable would be to relax Choice, given that the AC
seemed to be essential in "cooking up" non-Lebesgue measurable sets.  Of course, some alternative principle strong enough
to yield a worthwhile theory of Lebesgue measure and integration would be desirable.  Around 1970, Solovay hit that particular
home run; he showed a model could exist (granting existence of an inaccessible) enjoying the principle of Dependent Choice (DC),
and with all sets Lebesgue measurable.  Though AD did not hold in the model introduced in that celebrated paper, he speculated
a large cardinal axiom might ensure that AD held in the inner model L($\bf{R}$).

There were now opening up several paths through the still largely impenetrable forest of Set Theory, in addition to forcing. Large
cardinals; inner models; and determinacy.  Would any compelling results pull the various themes together, perhaps in some such bigger,
better inner model than L.  In the late 70s Solovay also showed the important principle of Dependent Choice was actually independent of
Determinacy.  What would it take, for DC to co-exist with the Axiom of Determinacy?

Then -- in 1984 -- Alexander Kechris got the needed breakthrough.  ZF + AD + V=L($\bf{R}$) implied DC.  As Ronald Jensen
has put it, this model is an analyst's dream.  All subsets of $\bf{R}$ in the model L($\bf{R}$) are Lebesgue measurable.  They enjoy the perfect
set property, so the Weak Continuum Hypothesis holds.  (There are no "intermediate" infinite sets, bijectable with neither the
integers nor the reals.)

A final connection in this regard is that indeed (as Solovay had speculated) an appropriate large cardinal, a supercompact, suffices
to ensure AD holds in L($\bf{R}$).  That was later "brought down" to the existence of an infinite number of Woodin cardinals, with a
measurable cardinal above them all.

Comment: You are misrepresenting just about every fact that you state. Just to give you an example: That $\mathsf{DC}$ holds in ${\mathrm L}(\mathbb R)$ is trivial from the fact that it holds in ${\mathrm V}$, and has nothing to do with determinacy, it is simply that $\mathsf {DC}$ for reals relativizes down from the universe to its inner model ${\mathrm L}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: The point of Kechris's result is that we can prove $\mathsf{DC}$ in this model if in addition we assume determinacy, without having to assume any choice principles in the background universe. This is a significant structural result about determinacy, but it is not what your question was asking.

Comment: (Certainly Solovay's result should not lead one to wonder whether $\mathsf{DC}$ can "co-exist" with determinacy. Again, that is trivial.)

Comment: OK, I take your point about the significance of Kechris's result.  Is it at all obvious, though, that the full axiom of Choice does not relativize down from the universe to $\bf{L}(\bf{R})$, as compared to Dependent Choice?